# External database access, my app crashes

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Yes I have searched for many solutions for days. My still persisting problem is **my app crashes at start** when I am trying to **access an external database** (created through "*DB Browser for Sqlite*" named "test.db"). 
The sole purpose is of course to **prepopulate** my app with some data.

I have kept the database file on assets folder in android studio. Finally I have implemented a helper class to access the database.

Here is the helper class:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static String DATABASE_PATH = "";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context myContext;

public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        DATABASE_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    } else {
        DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public void createDatabase() throws IOException {
    createDB();
}

private void createDB() {
    boolean dbExists = checkDatabase();
    if (dbExists) {
        //do nothing
    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDatabase();
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkDatabase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        checkDB.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        throw new Error("SQLite exception");
    }
    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null;
}

private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
    InputStream myInput = null;
    OutputStream myOutput = null;
    String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

    try{
        myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
        myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }catch (IOException ie){
        throw new Error("Copydatabase run error ");
    }

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if(myDataBase != null){
        myDataBase.close();
    }
    super.close();
}
}
```

In the Main activity I have just called the createDatabase() method of the helper class. The code being below:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    try{
        myDbHelper.createDatabase();
    }catch (IOException ioe){
        throw new Error("Unable to CREATE DATABASE");
    }
}
}
```

The logcat indicates the problem as:

> AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.Error: SQLite
>   exception at DataBaseHelper.checkDatabase(DataBaseHelper.java:79) at
>   DataBaseHelper.createDB(DataBaseHelper.java:59) at
>   DataBaseHelper.createDatabase(DataBaseHelper.java:55) at
>   MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)

which points to my checkDatabase() method. But now I am not able to sort out the problem.

I am using Android Studio 3.0.1, DB Browser for Sqlite 3.10.1, Min API level used 17.

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
 public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "abc.db";
 public final static String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/"+ PACKAGE_NAME + 
 "/databases/";
 public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


  public void createDatabase()  {
    boolean dbExist1 = checkDataBase();
    if (!dbExist1) {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            this.close();
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

// Check database already exist or not
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    boolean checkDB = false;
    try {
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        File dbfile = new File(myPath);
        checkDB = dbfile.exists();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
    }
    return checkDB;
}

// Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
// empty database in the system folder
public void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    InputStream myInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myInput.close();
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
}
```

Comment: ok on createDatabase() I added the this.close(); and used whole checkDatabase(); and it worked like charm. Thank you very much. Finally if you want, could you tell me how this.close(); helps here. Anyway I am really grateful.